# Define <Image/> tag in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

What I want is my GUI component (exported as jar file, and used by another component) can change the image dynamically by using images that stores in an image folder which is next to its jar file. Thus using url in  tag is not a choice since no matter how I try, my jxml file can't locate the image resource when it is not included in the jar file. 

Thus I try like this:

> In my avatar.jxml file

```
<ImageView>
    <image>
        <Image fx:id="myImage"/>
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

> In my Java file

```
public Image myImage = new Image("location of an image stored on computer");
URL location = getClass().getResource("avatar.fxml");
ResourceBundle resources = ResourceBundle.getBundle("myResource");
FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(location, resources);
Pane root = (Pane)fxmlLoader.load();
MyController controller = (MyController)fxmlLoader.getController();
```

But when I try to run the program, javaFX throws exception and require url in the Image tag should not be null. 

Can someone please show me what did I do wrong ?

Thank you very much.

P/S the code was simplified for your reading convenience. I'm using Java 8.

Comment: What is a jxml file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, an `Image` must be initialized with the URL of the image data.

If you want to be able to dynamically change the image that is displayed, you need to inject the `ImageView` (which can be initialized "empty", i.e. without an image) into your controller, and then set the image on it as you need.

So in FXML just do

```
<ImageView fx:id="myImageView" />
```

and in the controller do

```
public class MyController {

    @FXML
    private ImageView myImageView ;

    public void initialize() { // or in an event handler, or when you externally set the image, etc
        Path imageFile = Paths.get("/path/to/image/file");
        myImageView.setImage(new Image(imageFile.toUri().toURL().toExternalForm()));

    }
}
```